# Почему не приходит ответ с сервера при асинхронном выводе постов в WordPress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Предисловие, сделал пользовательский тип записей "Объекты недвижимости"(buildings). Для них накидал пользовательские поля, по которым в последствии собирался фильтровать эти записи.
Делал по данному гайду: https://misha.blog/wordpress/filtryi-zapisey-i-tovarov.html

В итоге имею следующую форму:
[image: Изображение формы]

Проблема в том, что посылая параметры 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ajax запрос успешно отрабатывает, но я получаю абсолютно пустой response.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметку формы решил залить в пастбин, чтоб не уйти в лимит: https://pastebin.com/8VJVbf3m

filterAjax.js :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter_complex').submit( function(){
        var filter = $(this)
        $.ajax({
            url: myajax.url, // обработчик
            data: filter.serialize(), // данные
            type: filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                filter.find('button.btn-primary').text('Загружаю...') // изменяем текст кнопки
            },
            success: function(data){
                filter.find('button.btn-primary').text('Применить фильтр') // возвращаеи текст кнопки
                $('#response').html(data)
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('Ошибка: ' + data)
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

php обработчик в function.php:

```
function complexFilter_function(){

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'buildings',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'meta_query' => array( 'relation'=>'AND' )
        );

        // Условие 1: цена больше $_POST['priceFrom']
        if( isset( $_POST['priceFrom'] ) && ($_POST['priceFrom'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => $_POST['priceFrom'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>'
            );

        // Условие 2: цена меньше $_POST['priceTo']
        if( isset( $_POST['priceTo'] ) && ($_POST['priceTo'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => $_POST['priceTo'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<'
            );

        // Условие 3: Жилищный комплекс
        if( isset( $_POST['housing_complex'] ) && ($_POST['housing_complex'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'housing_complex',
                'value' => $_POST['housing_complex'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );


        // Условие 4: Район
        if( isset( $_POST['district'] ) && ($_POST['district'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'district',
                'value' => $_POST['district'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 5: Метро
        if( isset( $_POST['metro'] ) && ($_POST['metro'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'metro',
                'value' => $_POST['metro'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 6: ЖД / Станции
        if( isset( $_POST['station'] ) && ($_POST['station'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'station',
                'value' => $_POST['station'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 7: Город
        if( isset( $_POST['city'] ) && ($_POST['city'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'value' => $_POST['city'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 8: Район ЛО
        if( isset( $_POST['lo_district'] ) && ($_POST['lo_district'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'lo_district',
                'value' => $_POST['lo_district'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 9: Комнатность
        if( isset( $_POST['room'] ) && ($_POST['room'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'room',
                'value' => $_POST['room'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 10: Общая площадь
        if( isset( $_POST['space'] ) && ($_POST['space'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'space',
                'value' => $_POST['space'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => '>'
            );

        // Условие 11: Год сдачи до
        if( isset( $_POST['yeardo'] ) && ($_POST['yeardo'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'yeardo',
                'value' => $_POST['yeardo'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 12: Отделка
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-facing'] ) && ($_POST['feature-facing'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'furnish',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-facing'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 13: Ипотека
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-mortgage'] ) && ($_POST['feature-mortgage'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'mortgage',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-mortgage'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 14: Переуступка
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-assignments'] ) && ($_POST['feature-assignments'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'assignment',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-assignments'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 15: Спецпредложение
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-specialOffer'] ) && ($_POST['feature-specialOffer'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'spec_offer',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-specialOffer'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 16: Военная ипотека
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-armyMortgage'] ) && ($_POST['feature-armyMortgage'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'military_mortgage',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-armyMortgage'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );

        // Условие 17: Материнский капитал
        if( isset( $_POST['feature-motherCapital'] ) && ($_POST['feature-motherCapital'] != '') )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'm_capital',
                'value' => $_POST['feature-motherCapital'],
                'type' => 'binary',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );


        wp_die();
    }


    add_action('wp_ajax_complexFilter', 'complexFilter_function'); 
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_complexFilter', 'complexFilter_function');
```

UPD:: Добавил WP_DEBUG_LOG:
Логи показывают следующее:

```
[22-Nov-2018 16:44:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\nd\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 3071
[22-Nov-2018 16:44:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\nd\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 3071
```

А именно жалуется на этот метод:

```
public function next_post() {

        $this->current_post++;

        $this->post = $this->posts[$this->current_post]; //Эта строка
        return $this->post;
    }
```

Comment: Сперва я бы проверил наличие такого инпута: <input type="hidden" name="action" value="complexFilter"> Если он есть, то нужно смотреть логи, я более чем уверен, что данный AJAX-запрос завершается 500 ошибкой. Я бы включил WP_DEBUG_LOG и посмотрел логи в файле /wp-content/debug.log

Comment: @noname228 Input есть, WP_DEBUG_LOG подрубил, ничего не показывает, показывает только сторонний алерт, который не мешает работе, указал его в UPD.

Comment: Честно говоря, удивлён этой статьёй Миши. Этот код работать не может по определению. Обработчик php - пустышка. Ну, присваивает какие-то значения какому-то массиву, и что? После die() все это забывается. Обработчик должен выводить отфильтрованные посты с помощью echo, а потом завершать работу по die(). Весь вывод в таком случае попадет в js  код, который должен поместить вывод в нужный div.

Comment: Почитайте полную инструкцию о том, как работать ajax в WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html  попробуйте на простом примере, а потом уж беритесь за фильтрацию постов. В вашем обработчике должен быть полный цикл вывода, включая задание аргументов (что вы сделали), вызов WP_Query и цикл по постам.

Comment: @kagg-design дадада, вчера решил почитать досконально тему с ajax в WP и тоже понял, что обработчик в гайде ничего не возвращает. Но спасибо за ответ в любом случае, это наверняка поможет тем, кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Вы можете добавить этот ответ, я его отмечу как решение.

Comment: Нет, спасибо, это не ответ, не решение, а комментарий. Баллов репутации у меня достаточно, так что заходите с другими вопросами)